# message sending while pressing the button

Tags: android

I am creating basic application in android and i am beginner of the android devloping.

I am creating the application which the numbers of inbuild messages in that when user click on send sms then that message deliver to user using their message box

in that below gives the snapsot.

[image]
Please help to slove this problem..

Thanx in advance
@androidTec.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this blog post. Its fairly straightforward. [Android Button Tutorial](http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=93)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking us to do is write your application for you. Please read the Android Reference Guide for [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and the tutorial for Buttons Manish posted. If you run into more *specific* problems while trying to work it out, ask again.